# I broke my wifi interface configuration with wicd, how can I fix it?

Tags: networking, network-manager, wicd

Well, I was managing my wifi connections using wicd-gtk when I read the first option, it said something like "wired network" and a checkbox "use as default profile" and so on (not sure if its accurate, my os is in spanish). This option was checked and there was a dropdown with all the "profiles" (it was just 1 profile).

So seing that my laptop has neither ethernet adaptor nor wired connection I thought it was pointless and I deleted the profile.

To my surprise I broke all network connectivity in my laptop and can't get it back to work. I'm on the phone so its kinda hard to paste code. So far all I've tried is editing `/etc/network/interfaces` adding the lines `auto wlp1s0 iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp` and it looks like nothing's wrong there (when I first opened the file it just had `auto lo iface lo inet dhcp`). Also tried restarting network-manager and networking and it tries to connect but fails. When I run ifdown & ifup on wlp1s0 (my wifi adapter) it says `no DHCPOFFERS received` after 24 `DHCPDISCOVER on wlp1s0`. I want to avoid reinstalling the os (Ubuntu 18.04 lts) but I think I completely broke it and will have to do it eventually if I want to use wifi again...

I don't know where to look, and what config file to look for, it seems I deleted a profile and I don't know how to restore it. Thank you in advance!

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit:

I think I might have a clue: when I use `nmcli` this is the output:
[image]
It says wlp1s0 not available, not sure if it is because I reverted the changes on `etc/network/interfaces` to what I found when I first opened it. And if I run `nmcli decice show wlp1s0 | grep IP4.DNS` it doesn't give any output.

Edit2:

Reverted all to a state where nmcli recognizes the iface but it fails to connect.

[image][image][image]

The last picture says: "failed connection. Network connection activation failed" or something like that.

Comment: Why did you install Wicd? Wasn't Network Manager performing as expected?

Comment: I was using qtile and wanted a gui ntwk manager to manage my connections, the gnome one doesn't work properly with qtile. I entered the Ubuntu session to see if I could fix it with gnome network manager, but I broke it for good...

Comment: Please start by reverting your changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` and reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: Well, when I first opened `/etc/network/interfaces` after deleting the profile on wicd-gtk it only had this: `auto lo iface lo inet loopback` the change I did was adding `auto wlp1s0 iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp` removing those lines does nothing :/

Comment: I am quite certain that nmcli, a part of Network Manager, says that the wireless interface wlp1s0 is not managed because you have asked Wicd and also `/etc/network/interfaces` to handle it. Now that you have reverted the interfaces file, does Wicd see and manage your wireless?

Comment: I reverted all, also changed in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` the line `managed=false` to `managed=true`. And now it recognizes and manages the iface, but when I run `nmcli` it nos says disconnected. I think I need to run `nmcli con up id <profile> iface wlp1s0` but I think that "profile" is what I deleted with the gui wicd-gtk and I don't know where to look my profiles or how to create a new profile. I'll add pictures on edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108133/discussion-between-chili555-and-wonky).